# Bot identifies music category uploaded in conversation in azure cognitive services

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-search, azure-bot-service

I am working on a real-time problem to identify an emotion of the music. I would to do this with Azure bot framework and my challenge here is to make bot which I create to accept the music file upload mechanism in between the chat conversation and need to identify the emotion of the music and categorize it.

The thing I also want to make my bot to identify is the original album recognition of the music bit uploaded.

I hope this sounds crazy, but I would like to combine azure bot services, cognitive services and natural language processing to work in my bot.

Any solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

In combine, there is no such solution till now as new voices are added recently into the speech algorithms. There is a possibility to do this individually.

1. Create a chatbot with azure bot framework and enable to upload the files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-files

2. When the files are uploaded, it must be connected to a logic app where cognitive services are enabled.
3. Perform the task internally and present the result in the chat.

There are new language updates came out.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-new-voices-and-emotions-to-azure-neural-text-to-speech/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and can I get code for help in this scenario.